# How can to set Power setting turn off: never , by c#

Tags: c#, power-saving

How can to set Power setting turn off: never , by c#?
manualy:
Control Panel-> Power Options -> Edit Plan Setting -> 
trun off the display = never
Put the computer to sleep = never

anther Question:
to set: 
Don't require a password
manualy:
Control Panel-> Power Options -> System Setting
* Don't require a password

Comment: I need an answer for setting Power Option

Comment: Are you trying to prevent the computer from sleeping while your program is running, or are you trying to change the persistent setting?

Answer (score 0):

[Power Management in Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxkc1kwd.aspx)

[cPower - Windows Power and Battery, Information / Functions Stub](http://thoughtso.org/wp-content/uploads/2007/11/cpower.txt)

Answer (score 0):

Also check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724947(VS.85).aspx, it's win32 API but allows you to set some of the power/screen saver settings.