# How can Set power settings turn off: never (turn off the display= never, put the computer to sleep = never), by c# code

Tags: c#, .net

How can Set power settings turn off: never (turn off the display= never, put the computer to sleep = never), by c# code

[image]

Comment: This Powershell cmd is a start in the right direction:  Get-WmiObject -namespace "root\cimv2\power" -Class Win32_PowerPlan | Where-Object -Property IsActive -eq True

Answer (score -1):

The link given in this question can show you a way. [Programmatically change Windows power settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802301)

and same question asked by a user called sari before, maybe you asked again before. [How can to set Power setting turn off: never , by c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699917/how-can-to-set-power-setting-turn-off-never-by-c)

and again a user wrote a comment of possible duplicate with this question [Disabling Screen Saver and Power Options in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284601/disabling-screen-saver-and-power-options-in-c)

and :)) I think you question has a few possible duplicates